# Use condition to extract only part of np.array

Tags: python

I have an np.array `h_data` containing nine individual np.arrays of the same length. I would like to sort out data by using the variable latitude (third array of h_data). Condition works, see codeline below. 
When I try to use my condition on my h_data array I get an error.
I do understand why that error occurs. The lenght of `cond_lat` and of `h_data` are different.
How do I solve that problem?

```
cond_lat = (h_data[2,:] >= -25.901) & (h_data[2,:] <= -15.901)
new_h_data = h_data[cond_lat]
```

Traceback

File "read_NetCDF.py", line 153

new_h_data = h_data[cond_lat]

Index error: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Comment: What's the error? Is it `IndexError` or something else? please provide the full traceback

Comment: Question edited, full traceback provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
new_h_data0 = h_data[0,:][cond_lat]
new_h_data1 = h_data[1,:][cond_lat]
new_h_data2 = h_data[2,:][cond_lat]
new_h_data3 = h_data[6,:][cond_lat]

new_h_data = np.array([new_h_data0, new_h_data1, new_h_data2, new_h_data3])
```

Does what I want. But looks ugly.

Comment: And `0, 1, 2, and 6` are the indices where the value is `True`?